# Invoking bamboo plan remotely

Tags: bamboo

I know it is possible to take down a bamboo artifact remotely, I was wondering is it possible to take start a bamboo from a remote box by sending an appropriate HTTP request?

Thanks,.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
curl --user un:pwd -X POST -d "stage&executeAllStages" -d "bamboo.variable.TEST=WORKS" http://10.0.0.0/rest/api/latest/queue/CAP-BR.json
```

As you can see I am also passing an optional value to Bamboo `bamboo.variable.TEST=WORKS`

Comment: How do I do the above with the `requests` package?  I don't know how to specify both sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, then what you want to do is to trigger a build via the rest api of bamboo.

This could offer you some help:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/65517/trigger-bamboo-plan-via-rest-call